# Text.StartsWith but with a number field?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I've got the below as a transformation step against a table, but it isn't working. I think it's due to the fact that it's not a text field, but a number field.

[image]

```
= Table.ReplaceValue(
     #"Custom1",
     each [Sign],
     each if Text.StartsWith([Account No], "4") then -1 else [Sign] ,
     Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Sign"}
 )
```

If I create a Step with the following, I get correct results for those [Account No] valuese that start with a 4.

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Replaced Value2", "AccountNoStartsWithFour", each Text.StartsWith([Account No], "4"))
```

Does anyone know what I need to do to get this working?

There are values such as:

```
4001

4201

1240

3556
```

I have a sample file here: https://easyupload.io/7v68iw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you require?

[image]

```
= Table.ReplaceValue(AccountNoStartsWithFour, each [Sign] ,each if Text.StartsWith([Account No], "4") then -1 else [Sign],Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Sign"})
```

Comment: Thanks David, appreciate the assistance. I've tried both and doesn't seem to work :( It's really strange. I've shown some sample data in my original post - apologies for missing it.

Comment: What is the error. Can you post a .pbix?

Comment: Sure, do you know how I can do it? I have a file ready with the issue.

Comment: I've uploaded a file to https://easyupload.io/7v68iw - not sure how to upload to stack directly.

Comment: Sorry - what is the desired outcome as your test file appears to be working. AccountNoStartsWithFour2 already shows true where the account starts with a 4.

Comment: I've updated with what I think you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks so much David, that did the trick :) Looks like ReplaceValue rather than ReplaceText was key. Hope you have a good New Years :)